# Error trying to train the neural network - 'Namespace' object has no attribute 'steps_for_validation'

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, object-detection

I am following a tutorial called "Object Detection on Custom Dataset with TensorFlow 2 and Keras using Python"

I'm working on colab at this [link](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1ldnii3sGJaUHPV6TWImykbeE_O-8VIIN) https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1TdhgBFaMxsaxl8sBKtCpT-itMxiphliu

The thing is there is a problem when I try to train the neural network in this line:

```
'/content/keras-retinanet/keras_retinanet/bin/train.py' --freeze-backbone --random-transform --weights {'/content/keras-retinanet/snapshots/_pretrained_model.h5'} - -batch-size 8 --steps 500 --epochs 10 csv '/content/keras-retinanet/annotations.csv' '/content/keras-retinanet/classes.csv'
```

Throw an error:

```
File "/content/keras-retinanet/keras_retinanet/bin/train.py", line 521, in main
     validation_steps = args.steps_for_validation,
AttributeError: 'Namespace' object has no attribute 'steps_for_validation'
```

The train.py code where the problem is is this:

```
# start training
    return training_model.fit_generator(
        generator=train_generator,
        steps_per_epoch=args.steps,
        epochs=args.epochs,
        verbose=1,
        callbacks=callbacks,
        workers=args.workers,
        use_multiprocessing=args.multiprocessing,
        max_queue_size=args.max_queue_size,
        validation_steps = args.steps_for_validation,
        validation_data=validation_generator,
        initial_epoch=args.initial_epoch
    )
```

But I can't understand the problem well because there is no attribute error.

Also I'm following this github page that the same error appears [here](https://github.com/fizyr/keras-retinanet/issues/1223).

Every help it is appreciated

Comment: please share your code

Comment: @AdamStrauss in this link it is my code https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1TdhgBFaMxsaxl8sBKtCpT-itMxiphliu I'm working on colab.

Comment: @Sebastián You have pasted a long page of code, but what do we need to help you is the source code of `train.py`, you should paste that here or a link if it's long. Or better yet, you should try to understand the problem yourself and present a simpler case that can reproduce the same problem.

Comment: @satoru edited question

Comment: @Sebastián It seems to be a bug of keras-retinanet.

Comment: @satoru thanks for answer it, I will downgrade keras-retinanet to see what happends

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with `train.py` file of `keras-retinanet` library.

If you look at its code, while parsing the arguments in `parse_args` function, they have added default values for all the parameters using `parser.add_argument()` function except for `steps_for_validation`, `max_queue_size` and `initial_epoch`.

The workaround is to either

1. remove these lines from `fit_generator()` function call or
2. pass arguments with its name from your command line or
3. add `parser.add_argument()` function call for these 3 parameters in the `keras_retinanet` library and if required, built it.

Though I suggest to use 1st workaround, in case you do not know what these parameters are doing and what its default parameters should be.